# how to integrate my controller/function to jquery

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I have jquery like this but it seems it cannot read the controller/function

```
$('#submit').click(function(){

    $.ajax(
    {
    url:'controller/function',
    type:"POST",
    success:function(data){

         $(".content").load(url); 

        }
    }
    )
});
```

can anyone tell me whats wrong or give other solution.

Comment: `it cannot read the controller/function` since i bet you gave a worng path.. that is why it cannot read the controller function...try using proper path..

Comment: Have you tried giving url like this -  url:"@Url.Content("/controller/function")",Also try specifying dataType property.

Comment: thanks for the codes but when i click the button nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution I came up with awhile ago.

In your html head tag add this.

```
 <script>
      var site = "<?php echo site_url(); ?>";
 </script>
```

Then in your .js file you can do:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){

    $.ajax(
    {
    url:base + 'controller/function',
    type:"POST",
    success:function(data){

         $(".content").load(url); 

        }
    }
    )
});
```

Comment: thanks , i tried this but when i click the button nothing happens

Comment: Nothing happens? Does the click function perform. If so, is there an error being returned? 

Add this to your ajax call.
      success:function(data){
     },
     error: function(response){
        console.log(response); // also try response.responseText
     }

Answer (score 0):

use [site_url()](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) function of codeigniter...

```
<?php echo site_url('controllername/functionname') ?>
```

> The above example would return something like: http://example.com/index.php/controllername/functionname;

try this

```
$.ajax(
{
   url:<?php echo site_url('controllername/functionname') ?>,
   type:"POST",
   success:function(data){

     $(".content").load(url); 

    }
}
```

**updated as per @kolby comment**

if you have this script in seperate js file thn..

create a global var `base_url` in head so that u get this variable in every file.

```
<head>
....//your stuff
<script>var base_url= <?php echo site_url();  ?></script>
</head>
```

and use this in ajax

```
url:base_url+'controllername/functionname',
```

Comment: its still the same when i click the button nothing happens it doesn't go anywhere

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that you use wrong path, do you have firefox, you can use firebug to get the response, what the response code is? and if you use spring mvc and log4j, you can set the log level to debug, then you can see what the url that you send to the server as well as whether it is got matched?

Comment: can you give step by step how to do this?

Comment: 1. install firefox and open you website with it. 2. install firebug plug-in. 3. move to the firebug console tab. 4. click the button you mentioned and pay attention to that tab it will show the url that you can as well as the post parameter and the response information. this can give you the hint what happened.